# Java String utility/method to union two strings

Tags: java, string

Is there any helper method or utility that actually gives me union of two strings.
For instance, if i have two strings as below:

```
String s1 = "Isabella,tom,hardy";
String s2 = "Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith";
```

I'm looking for a solution which will take above two strings as input and outputs the result as below:

```
General syntax:  s1.{method/utility}(s2);
output : Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith
```

Comment: That should be handled with a List, which can be converted into a string afterwards: `String.join(",", list)`

Comment: java doesn't provide any such implementation instead you can convert string into array list and add to has set or as suggested by @davidxxx

Comment: Define "union of two strings".

Comment: you could easily write your own method for this. java doesnt provide any so specific way of joining.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud  As i had required the utility in only one place in my project , i don't think writing my own method will add any value(correct me if i'm wrong)  but as suggested by davidxxx , i could consider a set and add the contents of both strings into set and later i can convert the set back to string and use this string at applicable places.For example {noformat}
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
set.add(s1);
set.add(s2);
String s3 = set.toString();
I could use s3 wherever applicable!
{noformat}

Comment: @Henry By union i mean Math union property.As i have already given an example in my question that if i have two strings s1 and s2 then it can be treated as s1Us2  which gives all the elements present in s1 and s2 without any duplicates.

Comment: @VRaj may be you are getting it wrong. First, there is no straight forward ready made util method like this in JDK and elsewhere. Second, as an answer below **spring-core** have something like util method, that could be used but just only for this method having the whole **spring-core** or other jar makes **no-sense** since you required this only once in your project. So Finally, you need to do this by yourself. So separate this logic out of your business methods, is the way of doing **clear-code**. And this is the **value** one should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that will do the union of two strings. You can also pass it a boolean flag to dictate case sensitivity.

```
public static String union (String s1, String s2, boolean caseInsensitive)
{
    // if either string is null, union is the other string
    if (s1 == null)
        return s2;

    if (s2 == null)
        return s1;

    // use linked set to keep ordering
    Set<String> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    // put all words from string 1 into the set
    for (String word : s1.split(","))
    {
        word = word.trim(); // remove surrounding space on word

        if (caseInsensitive)
        {
            word = word.toLowerCase();
        }
        unique.add(word);
    }

    // put all words from string 2 into the set
    for (String word : s2.split(","))
    {
        word = word.trim(); // remove surrounding space on word

        if (caseInsensitive)
        {
            word = word.toLowerCase();
        }
        unique.add(word);
    }

    // get back the format of comma delimiter for the union
    String ret = unique.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\] ]", "");
    return ret;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{   
    String s1 = "Isabella,tom,hardy";
    String s2 = "Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith";

    String union = union(s1, s2, false);
    System.out.println(union);
}
```

**Outputs**:

```
Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith
```

Comment: This solution not only gives union of two strings but also it eliminates leading space in every element starting from second element after splitting string.I have used this solution and it works well. Thanks

Comment: @VRaj No problem. Thanks for considering my solution.

Answer (score 6):

**First**, there is no method or utility provided by JDK to address the problem so straight forward.

**Second**, just for this simple utility importing a 3rd party jar or dependency is not a wise choice.

In this case its always a wise choice to write your own method of purpose.

```
public static String mergeString(String s1, String s2) {
        //check for null as the method doesnt fall in NPE
        if(s1 == null || s2 == null) {
            return null;
        }

        //split the given String to some list
        List<String> s1List = Arrays.asList(s1.split(","));
        List<String> s2List = Arrays.asList(s2.split(","));

        //get a Set and add the list items to it. LinkedHashSet
        //is used to maintain the given order.
        Set<String> stringSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(s1List);
        stringSet.addAll(s2List);

        //Then join them using java 8 provided Utility
        return String.join(",", stringSet);
    }
```

**NB:** as you mentioned in the comments you may need this type of utility only once in your project. But despite, this logic should be separated from out of your business method. This will make your code more clean and readable.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Since null handling is *undefined* in question, how do you know if it is incorrect? Perhaps it should work like SQL functions, where a null parameter generally causes a null result.

Comment: Yes it will return null for any of the provided string Null. It certainly could be changed as one want to implement. I just gave an example

Comment: Using [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) would be better than streaming.

Comment: @Andreas i have answered

Comment: @Andreas based on set theory, all elements should be considered in a union. If you return null, then you are losing all the elements in the other set.

Comment: @soorapadman You stole the code of this answer, and simply changed last line, without comment or explanation. Not cool.

Comment: ha ha the main point is `String.join()` which is missing here .

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis It depends on *contract* of the method, i.e. how the method is defined to handle nulls, and I see 3 potential ways to handle null: 1) NPE, 2) treat null as empty, or 3) define that any null ("undefined") causes null output. #1 is most common in Java code. #3 is standard for SQL functions. Without any explicit specification, we cannot determine what is "right".

Comment: @Andreas yes. that would be simpler. thanx. updated.

Comment: In general,most of java projects use Spring Framwork.So we don't need to build the wheels repeatly!

Comment: @lihongxu I think he didn't mention anything about that. But what I think is when it comes to write some utility method that should be free of other dependencies so that u can plug it anywhere you need.

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer. +1 for your valuable answer.

Comment: No, this shouldn't be the accepted answer. It just gets upvoted because it's already at the top. I wouldn't use this code in production. My answer is more production ready than this code. I take more into consideration; however, because my answer is at the bottom no one is lookng at it.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I guess no one here is giving anyone the ready made production code. Suggesting idea is all that we focus. You can not handle the imaginary requirements that is not asked or concerned about in the question. Sharing the idea is all I am interested in. I am not asking anyone to just copy and paste my code. Instead take my idea and do your own code. So claiming **production ready** sounds ambigious. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `org.springframework.util.StringUtils`

Add a maven dependency [spring-core](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-core%22%20AND%20v%3A%223.2.8.RELEASE%22):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Use StringUtils:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Isabella,tom,hardy";
        String s2 = "Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith";
        String[] outputArr=StringUtils.mergeStringArrays(s1.split(","),s2.split(","));
        String output=StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(outputArr);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith
```

Comment: Need to add https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/2.5.6    dependecy in maven

Answer (score 2):

```
public void unionString(String s1, String s2){

        String[] s1Ar = s1.split(",");
        String[] s2Ar = s2.split(",");

        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<s1Ar.length;i++){
            set.add(s1Ar[i]);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<s2Ar.length;i++){
            set.add(s2Ar[i]);
        }

        Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use LinkedHashSet which maintains the insertion Order to get desired output.Below is my code:

```
 public class UnionJava {
        static LinkedHashSet<String> hashSetString = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        static String s1 = "Isabella,tom,hardy"; static String s2 = "Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith";
        public static void main(String args[]){
            String[] set1 = s1.split(","); String[] set2 = s2.split(",");
            for(int i=0; i< set1.length;i++){
                hashSetString.add(set1[i]);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<set2.length;i++){
                hashSetString.add(set2[i]);
            }
            int j=0;
            for(Iterator i = hashSetString.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
                if(j==0){
                    System.out.print(i.next());
                    j++;
                }else{
                    System.out.print(","+i.next());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the java api, you might try :

```
public class StringTest {

private String string1 ="";
private String string2 ="";
private List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
private String[] stringa1;
private String[] stringa2;
private int output3 = 0;
private int output4 = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
 new StringTest().startApp();
}

private void startApp() {
 string1 = "Isabella,tom,hardy";
 stringa1 = string1.split("\\s+"); //array to split

 string2 = "Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith";
 stringa2 = string2.split("\\s+");

 for(int o = 0; o<stringa1.length; o++) {
  array1.add(stringa1[o]);  //adding to arraylist
 }
 for(int o = 0; o<stringa2.length; o++) {
  array2.add(stringa2[o]);
 }

  for(int outP = 0; outP<array2.size()+array1.size(); outP++) {
  for(output4 = 0; output4<array2.size(); output4++) { //iterating and removing double elements 
   for(output3 = 0; output3<array1.size(); output3++) {
    if(array1.size() > array2.size() && array2.get(output4).equalsIgnoreCase(array1.get(output3))) {
     array1.remove(array1.get(output3));
    }
    if(array1.size() < array2.size() && array2.get(output4).equalsIgnoreCase(array1.get(output3))) {
     array2.remove(array2.get(output4));
    }
   }
  }
 }
 array1.addAll(array2); //merging the lists

 for(String outPres1 : array1) {
  result += " " + outPres1;
 } 
 System.out.println("This is the output: " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A short version with no sanity checks using LinkedHashSet.

```
public void printUnion() {
    String s1 = "Isabella,tom,hardy";
    String s2 = "Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith";

    Set<String>mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    mySet.addAll(Arrays.asList(s1.split(",")));
    mySet.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2.split(",")));
    mySet.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String s1 = "Isabella,tom,hardy";
        String s2 = "Isabella,tom,hardy,victor,smith";
        Set<String> result = new TreeSet<String>();
        result.addAll(Arrays.asList(s1.split((","))));
        result.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2.split((","))));
        System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, someone's got to provide a streams solution:

```
Stream.of(s1, s2)
        .flatMap(Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```